# My java code stops and until I hit enter or any key it doesn't work when it just skips that line and goes on to the next one

Tags: java

I am a beginner java programmer. My homework was to create a product inventory.

> Write a java program to create product inventory management with basic
> details like product name, id, quantity. The program should run
> iteratively to get user choice until choose the exit option. The
> sample required output has been given below.

I created a class(Products) that has variables like name(String) and id&quantity(int) which could store values. Then I created a main class where I made an array of objects from the Products class where in each of the element of the array I could store details of a product(name, id and quantity). Then using while and switch I tried performing functions like adding new products, showing all products, deleting product and exiting the loop. After that I added 3 products using the add products case [This is output of adding products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uED35.png). Then I tried to display all the products that are stored, but it only shows the first 2 products. To better understand look at the picture.[This is the image of displaying all the products stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIQVS.png). Look at my java code to see what I tried.

```
import java.util.*;
class Products{
    String name;
    int id, quantity;
}

public class Task2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Products p[] = new Products[100];
        
        int h = 0;
        while(h!=1){
            System.out.print("23BEC7217@ Enter your choice: ");
            int ch = sc.nextInt();
        
        switch (ch) {
            case 1: //add products
            for(int i = 0;i < p.length;i++){
                    if(p[i] instanceof Products){
                        ;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Enter the product details: ");
                        p[i] = new Products();
                        sc.nextLine();
                        p[i].name = sc.nextLine();
                        p[i].id = sc.nextInt();
                        p[i].quantity = sc.nextInt();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            
                break;
            case 2 : //show products
            for(int i = 0;i < p.length;i++){
                if(p[i] != null){
                    System.out.println(p[i].name);
                    System.out.println(p[i].id);
                    System.out.println(p[i].quantity);
                    sc.nextLine();
                }
            }break;

            case 3://deleting products
            System.out.println("Enter the product id to delete: ");
            int id = sc.nextInt();
            int i = 0;
            while(i<p.length && p[i] != null){
                if(p[i].id == id){
                    p[i] = null;
                }
                i++;
            };
            break;

            case 4:
            System.out.println("Bye");
            h=1;
            break;
            
            default:
            System.out.println("Enter a valid number: ");
            break;
            
        }
    }
    }
    
    }
```

This is my complete java code and what I tried. I am very new to java and stack overflow so please ignore my mistakes and help with my problem.

Comment: You are running `sc.nextLine();` inside the `for` loop of showing the products. This means you try to read lines as much as there are already products in the array. When you, let say, have already 10 products in the array, you will be calling `sc.nextLine();` 10 times as well (and waiting for 10 inputs), for no reason.

Comment: @Progman thank u very much it worked but is there any alternative for sc.nextline() because if I remove that and try to replace it with System.out.print() or System.out.println() both give me "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException" error immediately after I give my first input(p[i].name). Again thank u so much for ur help:)

Answer (score -1):

try this code and tell me

```
import java.util.*;

class Products {
    String name;
    int id, quantity;
}

public class Task2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Products p[] = new Products[100];

        int h = 0;
        while (h != 1) {
            System.out.print("23BEC7217@ Enter your choice: ");
            int ch = sc.nextInt();

            switch (ch) {
                case 1: // add products
                    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                        if (p[i] == null) {
                            System.out.println("Enter the product details: ");
                            p[i] = new Products();
                            sc.nextLine();
                            p[i].name = sc.nextLine();
                            p[i].id = sc.nextInt();
                            p[i].quantity = sc.nextInt();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 2: // show products
                    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                        if (p[i] != null) {
                            System.out.println("Product Name: " + p[i].name);
                            System.out.println("Product ID: " + p[i].id);
                            System.out.println("Product Quantity: " + p[i].quantity);
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 3:// deleting products
                    System.out.println("Enter the product id to delete: ");
                    int id = sc.nextInt();
                    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                        if (p[i] != null && p[i].id == id) {
                            p[i] = null;
                            System.out.println("Product with ID " + id + " deleted successfully.");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Bye");
                    h = 1;
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Enter a valid number: ");
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```